# Azure. How to deploy VM from managed image with ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template

I have an managed image of VM, as described [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource) I need to deploy some VMs from that image with Managed Disk as OS disk. How can I do that with ARM Templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a regular VM arm template and replace `storageProfile` with this:

```
"storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images', 'imageName')]"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
```